# How can I disable double request for detected port in Nmap?

Tags: nmap

When I execute this command:

```
nmap -sT -p 5481,10212,19999,2308,102,502,20000,2000,44818,2222,47808,18246,910,912,1974,8086,8087,12397,12399,12401,20222,22202,46824,5002,802,27700,2869 --scan-delay 1s --max-retries 0 -Pn <IP>
```

I run into the following issue: whenever one of these ports is dectected, the request is sent again.

[image]

In this example, the port 2869 is up and I don't know why Nmap do a second check.

How can I disable the second request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second probe is not sent to determine the port state, but rather to determine whether the scan can speed up or if it needs to slow down. This is how Nmap is able to get reliable results quickly and not overwhelm the target. Generally, these probes are sent to closed ports, but if no closed ports are available then Nmap will use an open port. You can't prevent Nmap from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming here that by "second request" you're referring to the fact that nmap is completing a "three-way handshake" for each port.

This is a natural function of the scan type you've chosen (-sT is TCP scan).  In this mode the scanner completes a standard TCP connection which involves multiple packets being sent.

If you want to have a single packet based request, use -sS for SYN scan, which won't complete the handshake.

Comment: If you look at the image, you can see two connections syn-syn / ack-ack-rst / ack. I want to do only one. You should look at port 2869, it's the one that's up.

Comment: you might want to add that detail to your question, it's not super-clear that's what you're referring to.